# What is the best way to update Vue data from outside the app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

```
const app = createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      some_id: 0
    }
  }
})
```

I have an autocomplete on a field.
When a label is selected, I want to pass the id to a Vue app.

```
onSelectItem: ({label, value}) => {
    app.some_id = value;
}
```

This worked in an old v2 version of Vue.js.
Now, I can't even call the methods of the Vue app from other JavaScript functions.
What is the best solution?

Comment: Read about the composition-api. It allows you to have Vue functionality outside of components: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html

Comment: I don't see how that helps. I have a root component which is mounted to existing HTML. I don't use templates or other components.

Comment: " Now, I can't even call the methods of the Vue app from other JavaScript functions" - what did you try? You probably need https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#exposing-public-properties to expose a method in case you use composition api

Comment: @EstusFlask In my understanding, if you don't call expose() then everything is exposed. 
But I only tried using the Options API because I couldn't even figure out how to mount to existing HTML with Composition API. I don't need/want templates.

Comment: What exactly did you try? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's required for questions that address a specific problem with code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certain circumstances where you may need to access and mutate, change the instance's `data`.

This was easier in Vue JS 2, but Vue JS 3 has become more encapsulated. However it does not mean mutating state from outside is impossible. You can read about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data)

Supposing that you are using Vue with build steps, which covers most cases, you will have something like this:

```
const app = createApp({
    data() {
        return {}
    },
})
    .mount('#app');
```

Now if you head to browser console and type `app`, it will be null because it is limited to the scope of compiled `.js` files.

But if you attach `app` to a global object, `document` for example:

```
document.app = createApp({
    data() {
        return {}
    },
})
    .mount('#app');
```

Now if you type `app` in the console, it will no longer be `null`, but the Vue instance. From there, you can access the instance's `data` as well as mutate it via `app.$data` property.

Now what if the instance has `components` and you want to mutate their `$data`? In previous versions, it was possible to access children via `$children` property. But now in order to access children, you have to give each of them a `ref`, then access via their ref name. For example:

```
app.$refs.alertComponent.$data.message = "New message!"
```

Comment: I can't believe this.. Now it works. I spent hours trying everything, but couldn't modify app.some_id or app.$data.some_id. Now, the same code is working without any modification. I don't even use build tools. All the relevant code is in a <script type="module"> inline.
Maybe it was a bug in my browser?! Thanks anyway!